# Simple web push with node.js, how to do it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, push-notification, web-push

I'm trying to use the web-push plugin of node.js to implement push notifications on my web app.

```
// server.js

var webPush = require('web-push');

webPush.setGCMAPIKey("MY_API_KEY"); // I replace this with my key

router.post('/sendNotification', function(req, res) {
  webPush.sendNotification({ endpoint: req.query.endpoint }, "Payload test here");
});
```

I got no error but i don't receive any notifications....

```
// index.js

var endpoint;

navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
.then(function(registration) {
  return registration.pushManager.getSubscription()
  .then(function(subscription) {
    if (subscription) {
      return subscription;
    }
    return registration.pushManager.subscribe({ userVisibleOnly: true });
  });
}).then(function(subscription) {
  endpoint = subscription.endpoint;
}

document.getElementById('doIt').onclick = function() {
  fetch(
    './sendNotification?endpoint=' + endpoint,
    { method: 'post' }
  );
};
```

.

```
// service-worker.js

self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    self.registration.showNotification('header test', {
      body: 'body test',
    })
  );
});
```

So when i click on my btn (#doIt), the server route **/sendNotification** is called well, with the right endpoint but... no notifications happend !

Hope you will be able to help me ! Thanks in advance !

Comment: `.then(function(subscription) { endpoint = subscription.endpoint; }` is in the wrong place: it must follow `.getSubscription()`, not the service worker registration. BTW building from scratch is quite hard: have you considered using a service? e.g. Pushpad has a [node-js library](https://github.com/pushpad/pushpad-node).

Comment: I am actually using web-push which seems to be the official library and works fine on the example i wrote [on serviceworke.rs](https://serviceworke.rs/push-payload.html).

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need the GCM API key, but you do need VAPID keys, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-push#usage . Make sure you have VAPID keys call `webPush.setVapidDetails()`. If you're looking for a more detailed guide, I wrote a [blog post on web push with Node.js](https://thecodebarbarian.com/sending-web-push-notifications-from-node-js.html).